# How to convert unixtime to datetime by oneself

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, unix-timestamp

I wanna convert unixtime to datetime without using datetime.fromtimestamp.

Do you know how to create a method to convert unixtime to datetime in Python?

Comment: You could try looking at the datetime module source code and translate that logic from C into pure Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/datetimemodule.c#L3889-L3915

Comment: I did. however I want to convert datetime before the year 1900

Comment: `datetime.fromtimestamp(-22000000000) == datetime(1272, 11, 5, 9, 46, 48)` with my Python 2.7.

Comment: thanks. I could do it @Boldewyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you not to do that, at least until you have a wider overview over the problem set. A very naive approach might look like this (**do not use this!**):

```
def timestamp_to_datetime(ts):
    year = 1970 + ts // (60*60*24*365)
    day_in_year = ts % (60*60*24*365) // (60*60*24)
    hour = ts % (60*60*24*365) % (60*60*24) // (60*60)
    minute = ts % (60*60*24*365) % (60*60*24) % (60*60) // 60
    second = ts % (60*60*24*365) % (60*60*24) % (60*60) % 60

    month = day_in_year // 30
    day = day_in_year % 30

    return datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour,
                    minute=minute, second=second)
```

Of course, the result of this simple function is nowhere near the correct date. That we assume each month with 30 days is only the tip of the iceberg here.

- No leap years: We're off 13 days alone because of this
- No time zone: Was it a UTC timestamp? Local time? Which one?
- No [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second): The result will be off in subtle ways
- For negative timestamps we get negative `day_in_year` and directly a `ValueError` in the `datetime()` constructor. You need to handle those cases separately.
- Things I’ve likely forgotten, because date and time are terrible things to work with and I’m glad other more competent people wrote helper libraries to be used.